# How to change filter action when there's no input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make a typeAhead in AngularJs, and following [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-typeahead-widget-with-angularjs/) I have made it most of the way. The only thing that it doesn't do for me is that I want the whole list to show up when you first click in the box, instead of it waiting for input to show anything.
In the template it has

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" placeholder="{{prompt}}"
    ng-keydown="selected=false"/>
    ...
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:model  track by $index" 
        ng-click="handleSelection(item[title])" style="cursor:pointer"
        ng-class="{active:isCurrent($index)}" ng-mouseenter="setCurrent($index)">
```

I need to create a custom filter I imagine it would like a little like

```
.filter('psudoFilter', function($filter){    
    var original_filter = $filter('filter');
    return function(input){
        if(input.length === 0){
            return // What should I return if I don't want to change the data?
        } else {
            return original_filter(input_to_filter_items_by); //Filter as usual
        }
    }    
});
```

The problem I have is, what should the inner function return so that it doesn't filter when there is no input? how does the filter interact with the data it will actually be filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't really about the filter.  The problem is that the list of items is only visible if something is typed in the textbox:

```
<div class="items" ng-hide="!model.length || selected">
```

What you want to do is show the list when the textbox is clicked on.  I'm assuming you also want to hide the list when the textbox loses focus.  Add `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` events to the textbox.  I'm setting a `boxHasFocus` property in those events, and modifying the `ng-hide` on the list so that it displays when `boxHasFocus` is true.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" placeholder="{{prompt}}" ng-keydown="selected=false" ng-focus="boxHasFocus=true" ng-blur="boxHasFocus=false" />
<br/>
<div class="items" ng-hide="(!model.length || selected) && !boxHasFocus">
```

There's a problem with this though.  Originally, the list items looked like this:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:model  track by $index" ng-click="handleSelection(item[title])" ...
```

The problem is that the `blur` event fires before the `click` event, so the list disappears before it can register that you clicked on an item.  The solution is to use `ng-mousedown` instead of `ng-click`, because `mousedown` events get fired before `blur` events.

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:model  track by $index" ng-mousedown="handleSelection(item[title])"
```

Here's a [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FVK0tr5N4hkFjSaPa6Ic?p=preview) showing it working.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. Just out of curiosity where did you find the event order of mousedown then blur then click?

Comment: I just Googled around.  There isn't really a definitive spec regarding event order; each browser can implement it differently (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Only part this example does not handle is showing whole list when user clicks in it to start with. But that will be easy to hook up.

http://www.byteblocks.com/Post/Autosuggest-text-box-using-AngularJS